# Analysing graph from matplotlib

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

I'm currently making a device where it uses MyoWare Muscle Sensor to collect data , send it to the mysql database , and using matplotlib to display the graph. As this device is for sports purposes ( in my case weight lifting ) , i want to be able to determine the number of repetitions the user does. Does anyone know or can show me how can i achieve it ?

[Here is my graphs with 4 reps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdj50.png)

My python code

```html
conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="123456", db="XXX")
cur = conn.cursor()
query = """
SELECT CONVERT(data,SIGNED INTEGER),time FROM sensordata
"""
cur.execute(query)
data = cur.fetchall()
cur.close

cur =conn.cursor()
query1 = """
SELECT CONVERT(data1,SIGNED INTEGER),time1 FROM sensordata2
"""
cur.execute(query1)
data1= cur.fetchall()
cur.close
conn.close()

data,time= zip(*data)
data1,time1= zip(*data1)

data_moving_average = []
for initial_element_index in range(len(data)): 
    data_moving_average.append(sum(data[initial_element_index:initial_element_index+20])/5.)
data_moving_average1 = []
for initial_element_index in range(len(data1)):
    data_moving_average1.append(sum(data1[initial_element_index:initial_element_index+20])/5.)

plt.plot(time,data_moving_average)
plt.plot(time1,data_moving_average1)
```

What is inside my database

```html
+-----+------+---------------------+----------------------------+
| id  | data | time                | analyzetime                |
+-----+------+---------------------+----------------------------+
|   1 | 1    | 2017-06-22 08:23:09 | 2017-06-22 08:23:09.846534 |
|   2 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:10 | 2017-06-22 08:23:10.048035 |
|   3 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:10 | 2017-06-22 08:23:10.333497 |
|   4 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:10 | 2017-06-22 08:23:10.656422 |
|   5 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:10 | 2017-06-22 08:23:10.865791 |
|   6 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:10 | 2017-06-22 08:23:10.954816 |
|   7 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:11 | 2017-06-22 08:23:11.147128 |
|   8 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:11 | 2017-06-22 08:23:11.402207 |
|   9 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:11 | 2017-06-22 08:23:11.613567 |
|  10 | 0    | 2017-06-22 08:23:11 | 2017-06-22 08:23:11.867029 |
```

Comment: What exactly red and blue curves mean in your graph?

Comment: @BatyrkhanSaduanov they are the individual graph of two sensors that i'm using

Comment: @BatyrkhanSaduanov but in my case now , i would like to focus on the red one to determine the number of repetitions ( 4 ) . Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to count number of peaks.

You can use scipy,

```
from scipy import signal

peakind = signal.find_peaks_cwt(data_moving_average, np.arange(1,100))
nbOfRepetitions = peakind.size
print nbOfRepetitions
```

UPDATE:

I found better function for your task also using scipy

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

peakind = argrelextrema(x, np.greater)
nbOfRepetitions = peakind.size
print nbOfRepetitions
```

Comment: Is there a way to handle noise (for instance tell `find_peaks_cwt` to only look for peaks on a certain length scale)?

Comment: Okay, another way is to put a threshold of Strength, like Strength higher thatn 40 is considered as 1 repetition. So you will have to iterate through your strength matrix and count occurences when you strength matrix just crossed your threshold. Is this way is okay for you?